# Run ANT commands on Remote Linux server

Tags: linux, ant, redhat

I have an Ant script on one Linux box which does a series of task locally on that box. I would like to leverage that same script on other Linux boxes.

Is there a way I can tell Ant to connect to that remote linux box via SSH then run the series of task as if it was on that server without copying the Ant script to the remote servers?

I know it is possible to use `sshexec`, but I would have to do that for each `task`, which in the end become a different script.

```
<sshexec host="${remote.host}"
         username="${remote.user}"
         password="${remote.pass}"
         trust="true"
         command="rm -rf ${remote.webapps.path}/ROOT*">
```

Comment: ant uses task, did you look up any of the default ssh task on ant?

Comment: I came back with <sshexec> and <sshsession>. The sshexec works but not what I need. Would the <sshsession> work for my case? I can test that one out.

Comment: https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/sshsession.html

Comment: I would highly recommend to you consider using Jenkins to automate your builds. It supports "slaves" accessible via SSH, will automatically copy over all the necessary build scripts and record centrally each build result. All features provided free without the need to explicitly code it in your ANT build file.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can encapsulate all the steps performed in a shell script and call it via sshexec
2. you can also write a parameterized ant macro/target that captures all the ssh commands . In this case all you need to do is call this target with a command/script and that should reduce the burdne of copy pasting commands

You can always pass in a specific command via a parameter For ex

```
<macrodef name="ssexec-wrapper>
         <attribute name="exec-command/>
         <attribute name="remote.host"/>
         ##Other variables as required
         <sequential>
            <sshexec host="@{remote.host} ... command=@{exec-command} failonerror="false|true"/>
         </sequential>

</macrodef>
```